# Event handling in EXTJS

Tags: extjs, event-handling

I am reading a file and as and when I get new data, I want to raise events based on the nature of the data. These events would in turn trigger EXTJS Sencha drawings.

I'm new to EXTJS and have little idea about how to proceed with this. Can someone provide me with some useful information on the approach I should take?

Comment: you can use fireEvent() in extjs to raise an event from the code. Refer here http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-fireEvent    What do you mean by EXTJS Sencha drawings?

Comment: I need to construct an image based on the data in the file.
As a basic example, lets say the first line says 'draw a road', I need to draw one then read the next line -'draw a building', draw that and so on.
Will this be possible with EXTJS?

Comment: ExtJs supports chart like darwings. I am not sure what kind of drawing you exactly needed in you application. If the drawing you are saying is possible in ExtJS, then conditional drawing as per you example is possible. It all depends on the kind of drawing or image you are going to built.

Comment: Are there any examples or documentation or such that you can direct me to that'll help me figure out this conditional drawing?
I'm really stuck on how to make everything come together.
I need to draw network diagrams btw.

Comment: There is an external library named d3js https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery. this can be used to draw your diagrams like network diagrams. On what type of diagram will be drawn can be decided by d3js and the event for drawing is raised from extjs. So there will be one event and multiple diagrams based on conditions.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any examples of such event handling? I've googled but only found UI based event handling.

Comment: Me too did not find any examples as such. You have to figure it out yourself.:)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kendopunk/CqCDU/... this is the example for extjs + D3Js

Comment: Thanks a tonne, this will get me started !